# TexStudio auto-completer window not showing correctly

Tags: texstudio, windows, auto-completion

I am having a problem in using the autocompletion feature of TexStudio. When I start the autocompleter, I get a window that is not always being displayed correctly, due to the fact that it is "covered" by the limits of the TexStudio window:
[image]

I believe that the problem occurs when I use Windows windowsnap feature, although it may happen randomly sometimes. I could not find a person that has the same problem and it is getting pretty irritating. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sometimes it happens with me in Linux, but not with a so wider panel. It is better to ask here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/?source=navbar

Comment: The wider panel exists because I have checked the option to offer description of every command/completion. The reason why this is white in this example is because i have pressed ctrl-space on something, for which the suggestions do not have proper description. Anyways, I will also look in the link you suggested, thanks for that.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1688/ states this bug as fixed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report